# How do social security payments compare to investing the same amount of money in treasury bonds?

Tags: united-states, taxes, social-security, retirement

Social security tax is about 12% of income. The average income in 1950 was about 3k adjusted for inflation. If someone in 1950 worked a full career (30 to 65) and invested at a typical 10y treasury rate (2-5%) they would retire on a 15k income without social security.

The average Social security benefit is 15k.

The math for other government programs is largely the same.

Does the amount of money given to social security retirees roughly match what the average person receiving social security would get if they had taken the money and invested it government securities?

Comment: The government is about taking money from the current generation and giving it to the old generation.

Comment: Isnt that done in a self canceling way

Comment: "true but false" :-) https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/fact-checker/post/social-security-and-its-role-in-the-nations-debt/2011/07/11/gIQAp1Wl9H_blog.html

Comment: In the trivial sense that in the long term the government can't spend more money than it gets in taxes, this is true. But the same could be said for any economic activity. I'm voting to close this as unclear.

Comment: So basically all economic activity as you define it is pointless

Comment: In 1950 the average income per year was $3,210.00 and by 1959 was $5,010.00. You can't invest "inflation adjusted" dollars. Voting to close,

Comment: U.S. social security tax is 12.4% (including both employer and employee contributions) on the first $128,400 of wage income for 2018.  For those earning more than $128,400 or getting most income in a form other than wages, the effective rate is lower than 12.4%, so the 20% posited in the question is a substantial overcount.

Comment: @BobE There are some inflation linked bonds should be done for some of that period but the real rate of interest is lower

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Social Security was partially sold as a forced retirement savings plan. A more accurate reason for its existence was to combat rampant poverty among the elderly, which it has been immensely successful in doing. Social Security isn't a true savings plan for a handful of reasons.

1. Elderly people received payments immediately that never payed in.
2. A spouse can draw social security from a partner without paying anything in.
3. There is a maximum benefit which is much lower than equivalent savings amount for the 35 years required to qualify for it.
4. The actual financial situation for Social Security is a pay as you go system (i.e. government run Ponzi scheme).

Social Security is a wealth transfer program from the young working population to the elderly. There are a lot of benefits in keeping the elderly who failed to save or have no family to take care of them from living in poverty, and it's increasingly becoming a larger potential problem as many Americans are very bad at saving properly for retirement. A key benefit of Social Security is having a savings account that can't actually be touched, even retirement accounts can be loaned from, this keeps the program from being entirely welfare as those receiving benefits "payed in" a large portion or all of the benefits they received.

All government programs are taking money and giving it away. The key distinctions are that usually the people being taken from and receiving are different people. The goal is that those who are receiving get a larger benefit than the loss seen by those money was taken from. In the case of Social Security this is generally true.

Comment: does not answer the question. but mostly presents opinion.

Answer (score 5):

There's a couple misunderstandings in the question, I think the main one stems from the comparison of social security to personal, private savings. Social security is meant to be a safety net more than it is a savings plan. For your private savings option of buying bonds as you go, you would have to have been buying them from early in your career, whereas with social security you only need to have paid in for 10 years to extract benefits ([source](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/what-you-need-to-know-about-social-security/))

Another is the "inflation adjusted" historic salary and a misunderstanding on how bonds work. Adjusting for inflation and bonds aren't compatible, [inflation erodes the purchasing power of a bond's future cash flows](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/bonds/09/bond-market-interest-rates.asp), so you can't add together bond yield and inflation-adjustment.

Lastly is a somewhat implicit aspect of social security. Americans are [terrible at saving for retirement](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/05/15/how-much-americans-have-saved-for-retirement.html), and keeping any savings in this regard out of the hands of people until they actually need them proves beneficial in keeping the elderly out of poverty. And again, social security is meant to be more of a safety net than a retirement savings plan.

All that said, the Social Security Trust Fund does itself buy treasuries, so in a sense what you propose is happening. ([source](https://www.thebalance.com/who-owns-the-u-s-national-debt-3306124))

Answer (score 5):

Social Security tax is twice 6.2% of income, half paid by the employer.  If we include the employer's half, Social Security tax is 11.676% of income.  If we assume a 3% rate of inflation, that drops the 5% return to 2% in real terms.  But this also misrepresents how Social Security works.  It's not just a retirement program.  It's also a disability program.  Roughly an eighth of current benefits are paid for disability rather than retirement.  [Source](https://www.ssa.gov/policy/docs/quickfacts/stat_snapshot/index.html?qs) in Table 2.  So 10.2% is available for retirement.  Social Security tax was also lower in 1950, but let's ignore that.

If we assume that someone invested 10.2% of $53,100 (2018 dollars) every year, starting in 1985 and making a real (inflation-adjusted) return of 2%, that person would have $270,780.09 in 2020.  Assuming the 2% real return continues, that's enough to withdraw $15k each year for twenty-two years.  If the person lives longer than that, there's no money for that.

About one in four people live past age ninety.  [Source](https://www.ssa.gov/planners/lifeexpectancy.html).  You need a higher real return to reach that.  Say 4.8% from a 60% stock, 20% bond, and 20% bank mix.  [Source](https://www.cnbc.com/2018/04/11/6040-stock-bond-weight-rule-needs-to-go-on-a-diet.html).  That even provides some margin in case of a bad market for a few years.

Social Security pays more like $16,000 a year these days, but with stocks in the mix, this would still be enough.

A comment suggested that you can't invest "inflation-adjusted dollars".  This is literally true, but misleading.  You can invest the 1985 equivalent of $53,100 in 1985.  This might be $15,000 in 1985 dollars.  It doesn't really matter.  This is just a shorthand for saying $15,000 in 1985, $15,450 in 1986, etc.  This simplifies the math without making any real difference.  This is because the inflation-adjustment does part of the math for you already.  What is more true is that you can't invest real money at nominal rates.  You either need to use both real or both nominal.

In this post, I stuck to real (inflation-adjusted) amounts and rates.

I have also ignored that the Social Security trust fund runs out of money in the 2030s.  When that happens, unless they change something, the Social Security payment will drop by around 25%.  So roughly $12,000 in 2018 dollars.  Of course, they may do something by then.  But that could change the rate of return as well.

Answer (score 1):

Rate of return varies greatly from beneficiary to beneficiary. The **after inflation** returns are as follows:

> Among current workers and retirees, the rates of annual return varied
>   by about two percentage points - **from a high of 6.52 percent (for
>   single-earning couples born in 1920) to 4.52 percent (for their
>   counterparts born in 1985).** So if you wonder whether you will “come
>   out ahead” on Social Security, here are some key differentiating
>   factors to keep in mind:
>
> —**Younger workers will get less.** Today’s young people will see lower
>   rates of return, because they will have paid the highest payroll tax
>   rates of all the age groups compared in the SSA analysis.
>
> —**Couples do better.** Marital status is a key factor affecting Social
>   Security returns. In every age group, the best returns went to married
>   couples where one spouse works. That is because Social Security’s
>   design includes valuable spousal features that pay benefits to
>   nonworking spouses and surviving widows. Spouses are entitled to
>   receive the greater of his/her own benefit or half of their spouse’s
>   benefit. And surviving widows can step up to 100 percent of a deceased
>   spouse’s benefit.
>
> A single-earning couple with medium wages, born in 1943, will see a
>   4.59 rate of annual return, while a single female born the same year - also with medium wages - can expect a 2.49 percent return. (Spousal
>   benefits are also available in cases where a lower-earning spouse had
>   some earnings but so much less that their worker benefit is less than
>   half.)
>
> —**Longevity matters.** All pension and annuity systems are structured
>   around mortality credits - that is, they use assets of those who die
>   young to fund the benefits of those who live to a very advanced age. A
>   projection by Favreault of Social Security data found that 82 percent
>   of individuals who live to age 85 get back more in benefits than then
>   pay in taxes; about 52 percent of those who die between 75 and 84 come
>   out ahead. Meanwhile, just 21 percent of those who die between 62 and
>   69 get back more than they put in to the system.
>
> The odds here are especially good for women, since they have a higher
>   likelihood of surviving to retirement age and longer lives after
>   retirement. That gives them higher rates of Social Security return - a
>   medium-earning single female born in 1943 can expect a 2.49 rate of
>   return compared with 2.09 percent for her male counterpart.
>
> —**Lower-income workers come out ahead.** Low-income workers enjoy higher
>   rates of return by design, because Social Security’s benefit formula
>   is weighted toward lower-earning beneficiaries and their payroll tax
>   contributions will be relatively lower. A very low-income couple born
>   in 1943 will receive a 6.79 percent annual return, compared with 3.92
>   percent for their high-earning counterparts.

Treasury bond rates have [also varied greatly over time](https://www.macrotrends.net/2016/10-year-treasury-bond-rate-yield-chart) (also [here](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/New_Home_Page/datafile/histretSP.html)), mostly due to rising and falling inflation rates.

As other commentators have noted, however, Social Security is primarily a social insurance program and not a savings program. It protects people who haven't otherwise saved for retirement, people how have saved but made poor investments, and people have haven't had time to save (e.g. due to a disability or early death leaving survivors). It is more comparable to annuities and life insurance products than it is to treasury bonds. The returns actually compare favorable to stock market returns:

> [S]ome workers might beat Social Security’s returns in some years if
>   they took risks in the stock market. But over a lifetime, Social
>   Security’s consistent, risk-free and inflation-adjusted returns would
>   be very tough to beat.

What were stock market returns [in the long run](https://www.investopedia.com/walkthrough/corporate-finance/4/capital-markets/history-stocks-bonds.aspx)?

> Siegel also gives an average compound inflation-adjusted rate of
>   return of 6.8% for the stock market from 1802 to 2002.

The [inflation adjusted return on Treasury Bonds from 1900 to 2000](https://www.investopedia.com/walkthrough/corporate-finance/4/capital-markets/history-stocks-bonds.aspx) is 1.6%, about a third to a quarter of the return from Social Security taxation.

Pretty much everyone does much better than Treasury bonds in the return they receive on their Social Security tax dollars, in substantial part due to the benefits that old beneficiaries receive from population growth (the new generations that pay in are larger than the old generations that receive benefits).

Comment: Anecdotal, but having regularly put money into 401k & IRAs, mostly in index mutual funds, I expect to reasonably have more monthly income from them (using the MRD amounts) than I would waiting until age 70 to collect SS.  Of course not everyone will save rather than spend now, or go into debt.) The real difference, though, is that if I drop dead before spending all that IRA money, my heirs get it, whereas with SS they basically get nothing.  So SS is much more like a tontine than a Ponzi scheme :-)